# angular third party modules imported with forroot

Tags: angular

There are many third party angular libraries that are imported using `forRoot` method, and I was wondering if it is ok to import them inside my core module, instead of inside my app module, provided that my core module is meant to be imported only into the app module. I presume that `forRoot` is intended to keep the module services as singletons, so there shouldn't be a problem, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you only import your CoreModule in the AppModule.